# Why Daemonset pod will be allocated with ip which is exactly same as node ip

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I am recently maintaining a GKE cluster(data plane v2) and notice that in the namespace of kube-system, there are a lot of pods whose ip is same as the node ip. Is it intended? I understand that daemonset manages things at node level but still I can recall there is a k8s doc saying each pod should be assigned an unique IP.

Comment: If the answer provided helps you, a positive response is appreciated. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If not, I am happy to assist further.

Answer (score 1):

In general each pod will have its own ip address, If you are getting the same IP for multiple pods it can create an issue unless the pods are networking controller such as anetd pods.

From the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dataplane-v2#how_works):

> GKE deploys the GKE Dataplane V2 controller as a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) named anetd `to each node in the cluster`. anetd interprets Kubernetes objects and programs network topologies in eBPF. The anetd Pods run in the kube-system namespace.

So these types of pods may have the same ip as nodes which will not be an issue.

Comment: For more info check this [blog](https://www.hackingnote.com/en/kubernetes/networking).

Comment: I understand anetd-* pod shares the ip of the nodes. But I dont understand why we dont make them unique and seperate or what are the benefits of doing this. it is not mentioned in the offical documentation. Is it to save ip? But imagine there are a lot of daemon sets and they all share node ip. Will it cause any traffic routing issue?

Comment: Pod which will route traffic will have a unique ip or you will run into errors, this kind of issue happens in different situations like the anetd pod does not recognize the ip  or host network is enabled `(hostnetwork:True) `and it happens in rare scenarios which we cannot define.

Comment: HI, I still cannot wrap my head around this. Can you explain it a bit more straight. Anetd is network plugin and there are other  daemon pod like fluentd. They all share node ip. If it will cause issue, why don't we avoid it?

Comment: When a Pod is deployed with HostNetwork set to True. It gets the same IP address as the node. Otherwise the IP of the pod is assigned from a Pool of IP addresses you choose when you create the cluster. It's simpler really :)